# Script that deletes directories BUT doesn't delete directories with a specific .txt file

Tags: linux, bash, script

I got a folder that has a whole bunch of subdirectories.

I need to delete all of them EXCEPT folders that has a marker file say example: DONOTDELETE.txt inside the said folders.

Is this possible?

Already had a presolution Thanks to Benoit

```
( find /testftp -type d ;
  find /testftp -type f -iname DONOTDELETE.TXT -printf '%h'
) | sort | uniq -u | while read i
                     do
                        rm "$i/*";
                     done
```

but the output is:

rm: cannot lstat `/testftp/*': No such file or directory

rm: cannot lstat `/testftp/logs/*': No such file or directory

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Are you expecting one of us to write it for you?

Comment: Just asking for help Nifle. that would really be appreciated if you can give me an idea on this. Kinda new to scripting to be honest

Comment: Start looking at what [find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) can do. Use that in conjunction with [dirname](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?dirname) to find all dirs you want to leave alone.

Comment: Update your question (or better yet delete this one and ask a new) when/if you get stuck or have a partial solution.

Answer (score 2):

As shell fragment:

```
for i in *; do
     [ -d "$i" ] || continue # ignore non-directories
     [ -f "$i/DONOTDELETE.txt ] && continue  # ignore directories containing DONOTDELETE
     rm -rf "$i"
done
```

Comment: Hi Jakob...im new to scripting..can you explain further? :)

Comment: I'm confused at the moment lol...

Comment: Sorry for the delay :)

Comment: Every unix shell descended from the original bourne shell has control flow statements - while, for, if/else etc.

In this case, for is used. * expands to a list of files, and the for body is executed for every file.

"[" is a executable (look for /bin/[). It is also available under the name "test", read "man test". -d checks whether the next thing is a directory; -f checks whether the next ting is an ordinary file.

"continue" is a bash control flow construct, it behaves exactly like "continue" in java or c.

Comment: Any more specific questions?

Comment: Thanks Jakob..im almost there though...the above script edit under my question is almost done. I just can't figure out how to get the right thing that its suppose to do.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2598/discussion-between-joyian-yee-hernandez-and-jakob)

Answer (score 1):

How I would do that (maybe overcomplicated):

- Find all dirs
- Find all files named DONOTDELETE.TXT and print dir names
- Sort and uniq to keep unique lines

So:

```
( find . -type d ;
  find . -type f -iname DONOTDELETE.TXT -printf '%h'
) | sort | uniq -u | while read i
                     do
                        rm "$i/*";
                     done
```

Warning, if you have the following tree:

```
A/foo.txt
A/b/DONOTDELETE.TXT
```

Then the output of this last script will still output `A` because it does not contain a file named `DONOTDELETE.TXT`.

Another way:

```
find . -type f ! -iname DONOTDELETE.txt -delete
find . -d -type d -empty -delete
```

which first nukes all files that don't have this name, and second removes empty directory (`-d` explores subtrees first).

Comment: Really confused right now...sorry for being such a newb... wanted to delete all files under /ftptest except files that doesn't have the DONOTDELETE.TXT and your code seemed to be great...just really confused ATM. so sorry

Comment: find /testftp -type f ! -iname DONOTDELETE.txt -delete <--This worked for me. I had a /testftp/logger/ which contains DONOTDELETE.TXT and test.txt, It still deleted the test.txt, would like to happen to keep test.txt I really appreciate the contribution you gave Benoit

Comment: @JoyIanYee-Hernandez can you possibly have trees like the one I showed in my answer? Directory not containing the marker, having a subdirectory containing the marker? Should foo.txt be nuked or not?

Comment: With this ( find /testftp -type d ;   find /testftp -type f -iname DONOTDELETE* -printf '%h'; ) | sort | uniq -u I got a tree: /testftp
/testftp/logs <--- this directory does not contain the DONOTDELETE.TXT this is pretty close, just need to delete all the files inside that /testftp/logs folder

Comment: So, pipe that command into `while read i ; do rm "$i/*" ; done`.

Comment: hmm...( find /testftp -type d ;   find /testftp -type f -iname DONOTDELETE.TXT -printf '%h'; ) | sort | uniq -u | while read i ; do rm "$i/*" ; done   OUTPUT: rm: cannot lstat `/testftp/*': No such file or directory
rm: cannot lstat `/testftp/logs/*': No such file or directory

Comment: Oh By the way Benoit. the output of it is directories not files. the tree looks like: /testftp /testftp/logs

Answer (score -3):

```
find . -type f ! -name DONOTDELETE.txt  -print0 | xargs -0 ls -l
```

Comment: No, that will list files of which the name is different, but will still list files in the same directory.

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to get a hang of the find command. I tested this out and yeah it still lists the files that I wanted to keep. I'm playing around it and wanting for the specific folder to not exist on the ls -l and wanting to expect that folder that contains DONOTDELETE.txt won't come up

Comment: Rephrase question again and more and more people will jump in to help....